# Simulate an external keyboard on a Laptop's usb output

Tags: usb, laptop, keyboard

I have a laptop running Linux, a tower PC running Windows, and an USB to USB cable.

Is there a way to send my laptop keyboard's keystrokes to my tower PC as if it were an external keyboard using only these components and software?

I imagine an external keyboard generates some kind of patterns of bits which can easily be generated by software on my laptop, and then be controlled by the physical keyboard of my laptop.

Any other answers I could find used a network or a microcontroller, but I am looking for a way using only an USB cable. Is it possible?

Comment: This is an interesting question I won't be able to answer, but let me suggest you reveal which operating system(s) run(s) on your PCs.

Comment: Linux has support to emulate a HID USB device (keyboard/mouse). See https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/anpsnk/how_do_i_emulate_a_usb_hid_device_with_software/

Comment: @berndbausch the Laptop (source) is Linux and the Desktop (destination) is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot .  USB is a host/client based connection, meaning one end of the USB connection controls the other.  The ports in your computers are connected to USB ***host*** controllers.  You cannot connect a host to a host.

Comment: :( unfortunate... hopefully such limitations can be removed for future hardware.

Comment: @stimulate Its not a limitation, its design.  How would your laptop know to send the keyboard signals to the other computer?  How would the other computer know it was receiving keyboard signals?  USB is designed to connect a peripheral to a computer, nothing more.  Theoretically, you could do this, but you would have to write your own driver and software for both ends.

Comment: USB is no longer a host/client only protocol.  A laptop that can charge from a USB-C port, which is most of them, must be able to act as a client to a charger host to get a charge.  There are host ports, client ports, and dual role ports.  A dual role port, or DRP, allows a laptop to act as a host or client.  Because USB-C is complicated a USB-C DRP allows a laptop to appear as a host and client at the same time.  It is possible to connect two computers together and have one appear as a HID device to the other.  One needs the right software though.  The short answer is you can.

Comment: @MacGuffin do you know of any software I can do this with on Linux? I am currently using a free version of Synergy (called Barrier) to share my HI over network, which works well but introduces some latency and doesn't seem like a nice solution.

Comment: @stimulate  I've heard of the Linux USB gadgets project as a solution.  I haven't tried it myself yet and what I can find on it looks rather complicated.  The typical use is with small embedded or single board computers so the documentation and tools are built with that in mind.  It should work on any recent version of Linux on any recent laptop with USB-C.  The software and documentation is there, I just didn't dive in yet.  I'd start with "Linux USB gadgets" (without the quotes perhaps) on a search engine and look at some trusted sites for details.

Comment: @MacGuffin thanks a lot, I will try it out!